# unclicked/checked radio button still inputs 0 into db

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im working with this huge form were i have a lot of different inputs, a lot can be posted while empty. when the form is posted and a radio button group remains unchecked it will still input 0 into the database.

the db field is a tinyint and it allows null this is also the default value.

```html
<input name="participant" type="radio" id="partaker" class="with-gap" value="1"/>
<label for="partaker">Deelnemer</label>
<input name="participant" type="radio" id="participant_wait" class="with-gap" value="0"/>
<label for="participant_wait">Wachtlijst</label>
```

Comment: Please provide some code..

Comment: Web languages (JavaScript, SQL) assume that 0 == false/False. You should set the value for a checked checkbox to any other value, like 1, 2, 42..., or else your code is, how to say it, "special"... which decreases readability and maintainability a lot.

Comment: i have now. would you also need php code ? because its a lot. im using codeigniter btw.

Comment: so alex what your trying to say is instead of using 1 & 0 of 0,1,2, never use a 0 as an option. it actually seems like a good solution. thanks.

Comment: Your code shows a radio, not a checkbox. Forget what I said, because it only holds for checkbox, not for radio. The best solution to your problem would be to not allow keeping the radio unchecked, e.g. by adding `checked="checked"` to one of the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if using POST (otherwise, change POST to GET):

```
if(isset($_POST['participant']) && empty($_POST['participant']))
    $_POST['participant'] = NULL;
```

Alternative solution, use 1,2 for radio button

```
if(isset($_POST['participant']) && $_POST['participant'] != 1 && $_POST['participant'] != 2)
     $_POST['participant'] = NULL;
```

And if you want the values to be 0 and 1, then  just add an `else` statement:

```
else {
   --$_POST['participant'];
}
```

Comment: @GioCharlieHorse No prob :)